# What is the best approach to use EF Core to update parent and children?

Tags: c#, ef-core-6.0

I am learning EF Core and wondering what is the best approach to update the parent and children? I have a working example, but not sure if it is a correct one.

Approach:

- Check if parent and children exist or not
- If parent exists, then update values
- For children (list of `Suppliers`), it is a little tricky. I want to confirm if already exists, then update else insert

The logic I have is very simple, but I am not sure if I am leveraging EF Core to its full potential or not.

Code:

```
public class Operation : SqlAudit
{
    [Key]
    public int OperationId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long StockNumber { get; set; }
    [Required, MaxLength(10), Unicode(false)]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? EarliestPaymentDate { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public List<SupplierByOperation> Suppliers { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierByOperation : SqlAudit
{
    [Key] 
    public int SupplierByOperationId { get; set; }
    public int OperationId { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public long StockNumber { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
}

public class SqlAudit
{
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [Required]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; } = null!;
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2(7)")]
    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(255)]
    [Unicode(false)]
    public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime2(7)")]
    public DateTime UpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Service.cs

```
private async Task<Operation> UpdateOperationAndSuppliers(
    Operation operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var existingOperation =  await _dbManagement.OperationRepository.GetOperation(operation);
    existingOperation.Location = operation.Location;
    existingOperation.StockNumber = operation.StockNumber;
    existingOperation.EarliestPaymentDate = operation.EarliestPaymentDate;
    existingOperation.CreatedBy = operation.CreatedBy;
    existingOperation.UpdatedBy = operation.UpdatedBy;
    existingOperation.UpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
    existingOperation.Suppliers =  _dbManagement.OperationRepository.GetSuppliers(existingOperation).ToList();
    
    // Suppliers from request. If list contains same supplierName then only take first match
    var incomingSuppliers = operation.Suppliers
        .ToLookup(x => x.SupplierName).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
    
    if (existingOperation.Suppliers.Any() && incomingSuppliers.Any())
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < existingOperation.Suppliers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (existingOperation.Suppliers[i].SupplierName.Equals(incomingSuppliers[i].SupplierName) &&
                existingOperation.Suppliers[i].StockNumber.Equals(incomingSuppliers[i].StockNumber))
            {
                existingOperation.Suppliers[i].Location = incomingSuppliers[i].Location;
                existingOperation.Suppliers[i].Supplier = incomingSuppliers[i].Supplier;
                existingOperation.Suppliers[i].CreatedBy = incomingSuppliers[i].CreatedBy;
                existingOperation.Suppliers[i].UpdatedBy = operation.UpdatedBy;
                existingOperation.Suppliers[i].UpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Filter new records to insert
    var newRecords = incomingSuppliers
        .Where(x => !existingOperation.Suppliers.Any(y => y.SupplierName == x.SupplierName && y.StockNumber == x.StockNumber)).ToList();

    foreach (var record in newRecords)
    {
        existingOperation.Suppliers.Add(record);
    }

    var updatedEntity = await _dbManagement.OperationRepository.UpdateOperation(existingOperation);
    
    if (await _dbManagement.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken) <= 0)
    {
        throw new GraphQLException(
            $"[Unable to update, payload - {JsonSerializer.Serialize(operation)}");
    }
    
    return updatedEntity.Entity;
}
```

Repo.cs

```
public async Task<Operation> GetOperation(Operation operation)
{
    return await _dbContext.Operation.SingleAsync(_ => _.StockNumber.Equals(operation.StockNumber) && _.Location.Equals(operation.Location)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public IQueryable<SupplierByOperation> GetSuppliers(Operation existingOperation)
{
    return  _dbContext.SupplierByOperation
        .Where(supplier => supplier.OperationId.Equals(existingOperation.OperationId));
}

public async Task<EntityEntry<Operation>> UpdateOperation(Operation operation)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(_dbContext.Operation.Update(operation)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```